# python executes script twice when 'import csv'

Tags: python

Here is my test code:

```
import os
import csv

foo = os.listdir('C:/python27/USPTO-html/')

for oof in foo:
    if oof == '8916349.html' :
        print "..."+oof+'....'
print 'end'
```

When remove import csv, it executes once (prints end once)

When leave import csv in, it executes twice.. printing oof and end twice

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you import csv module?

Comment: file name is abcd.py

Comment: use csv in larger program, I isolated the problem down to this

Comment: Do you have another csv.py in the same directory?

Comment: no .. do not have csv.py anywhere except in Lib .. which came with the python 2.7 distribution

Comment: did have a csv.pyc file .. when deleted problem goes away

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the file you're running is not named `csv.py`.

`import` statement will cause the module to be executed (printing), and after the import statement statement will be executed (another printing)

Comment: @ScottFoerster, Check  if there is `csv.py` in the same directory.

Comment: no .. do not have csv.py anywhere except in Lib .. which came with the python 2.7 distribution –

Comment: @ScottFoerster, What is printed if you put `print(csv)` after the import statement?

Answer (score 1):

I had a file named csv.pyc in the same folder as the abcd.py program was testing. When I deleted csv.pyc, abcd.py only ran once.